# WiFi connection list is not displayed on my Ubuntu 15.10 with Lenovo 11e

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my Lenovo 11e.
Installation was complete but I don't see available WiFi connections when I click the WiFi icon on the top. Wired connection works fine. And when I installed Windows 10 on the machine, the WiFi worked fine.

Please advise.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

What's your output when you type this?

```
lspci
```

If you're wireless card isn't seen on list, download driver (unofficial, but still working) on http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true

Comment: I got "Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)".

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)